# reading from xml to a datagridview with bindingsource

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview with bindingsource contains three columns but one of them contains ComboBoxes.

with code below I can write to xml file but how can I read from it ?
 Appreciate your help

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, _
                   ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.BindingSource2.DataSource = Me.GetParentTable()
    Me.Column1.DisplayMember = "ParentName"
    Me.Column1.ValueMember = "ParentID"
    Me.Column1.DataSource = Me.BindingSource2
    Me.BindingSource1.DataSource = Me.GetChildTable()
    With DataGridView1
        .DataSource = Me.BindingSource1
        .AllowUserToAddRows = True : .AllowUserToDeleteRows = True
        .AllowUserToOrderColumns = False : .AllowUserToResizeRows = True
    End With
End Sub
Private Function GetParentTable() As DataTable
    Dim table As New DataTable
    With table.Columns
        .Add("ParentID", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("ParentName", GetType(String))
    End With
    With table.Rows
        .Add(1, "Parent 1")
        .Add(2, "Parent 2")
        .Add(3, "Parent 3")
    End With
    Return table
End Function
Private Function GetChildTable() As DataTable
    Dim table As New DataTable ("IOBOARD")
    With table.Columns
        .Add("ChildID", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("ParentID", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("ChildName", GetType(String))
    End With
    With table.Rows
        .Add(1, 3, "Child 1")
        .Add(2, 2, "Child 2")
        .Add(3, 1, "Child 3")
    End With
    Return table
End Function
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Save To XML
    Dim dt As DataTable = CType(BindingSource1.DataSource, DataTable)
    dt.AcceptChanges()
    dt.WriteXml("c:\so\Test.xml", System.Data.XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema, False)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: `dataset.ReadXml` method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [dataset.ReadXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.readxml.aspx) method?